# TypeScript: Correct type for passing an array of objects with a reduce

Tags: typescript

I'm getting a type error and I don't know how to structure the interface correctly

```
  const data = [
    { category: 'fish', age: 10, color: 'red' },
    { category: 'fish', age: 9, color: 'red' },
    { category: 'fish', age: 8, color: 'blue' },
    { category: 'fish', age: 7, color: 'blue' },
    { category: 'birds', age: 10, color: 'red' },
    { category: 'birds', age: 9, color: 'red' },
    { category: 'birds', age: 8, color: 'blue' },
    { category: 'birds', age: 7, color: 'blue' },
  ];

  interface CountProps {
    category: string;
    age: number;
    color: string;
  }

  const count = (dataToCount: CountProps) => {
    return dataToCount.reduce((t, v) => {
      const f = t.find((i) => i.category === v.category);
      if (f) f.total++;
      else t.push({ category: v.category, total: 1 });
      return t;
    }, []);
  };
  const summary = count(data);
```

The error im getting is `Property 'reduce' does not exist on type 'CountProps'.ts(2339)` and I dont know what types t,v,a should be.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `.reduce()` is an Array prototype, but `CountProps` is an object. I believe you actually mean an array of objects that is to be passed into the count function:

```
const count = (dataToCount: CountProps[]) => {
    // Rest of the logic here
}
```

You will also need to declare on the type for the accumulator, as TypeScript is unable to infer its type.

**Option 1**: Declare type in the callback

```
return dataToCount.reduce((t: Array<{ category: string, total: number }>, v) => {
    // Reduce logic here
}, []);
```

**Option 2**: Declare type in the source array

```
return dataToCount.reduce((t, v) => {
    // Reduce logic here
}, [] as Array<{ category: string, total: number }>);
```

---

Proof-of-concept code:

```
const data = [
  { category: 'fish', age: 10, color: 'red' },
  { category: 'fish', age: 9, color: 'red' },
  { category: 'fish', age: 8, color: 'blue' },
  { category: 'fish', age: 7, color: 'blue' },
  { category: 'birds', age: 10, color: 'red' },
  { category: 'birds', age: 9, color: 'red' },
  { category: 'birds', age: 8, color: 'blue' },
  { category: 'birds', age: 7, color: 'blue' },
];

interface CountProps {
  category: string;
  age: number;
  color: string;
}

const count = (dataToCount: CountProps[]) => {
  return dataToCount.reduce((t: Array<{ category: string, total: number }>, v) => {
    const f = t.find((i) => i.category === v.category);
    if (f) f.total++;
    else t.push({ category: v.category, total: 1 });
    return t;
  }, []);
};
const summary = count(data);
```

Comment: this gives me a new error `Property 'category' does not exist on type 'never'.ts(2339)` and the same on total

Comment: @Bill That's because TypeScript is unable to infer the type of the accumulator in the reduce callback: you need to provide a type manually :)

Answer (score 0):

I will simply adjust the declaration:

```
 const data: CountProps[] = [
{ category: 'fish', age: 10, color: 'red' },
{ category: 'fish', age: 9, color: 'red' },
{ category: 'fish', age: 8, color: 'blue' },
{ category: 'fish', age: 7, color: 'blue' },
{ category: 'birds', age: 10, color: 'red' },
{ category: 'birds', age: 9, color: 'red' },
{ category: 'birds', age: 8, color: 'blue' },
{ category: 'birds', age: 7, color: 'blue' },
];

interface CountProps {
  category: string;
  age: number;
  color: string;
}

const count = (dataToCount: CountProps[]) => {
  return dataToCount.reduce((t, v) => {
    const f = t.find((i) => i.category === v.category);
    if (f) f.total++;
    else t.push({ category: v.category, total: 1 });
    return t;
  }, []);
};
const summary = count(data);
```